# How to get the column range in A1 notation from header label?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am working with this code currently, but it is not as straightforward as I imagine it could be:

```
 var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
 var comCol = headers[0].indexOf('Header Label');

 rng = sheet.getRange(1, comCol + 1);

 var colStr = rng.getA1Notation();
 var colLtr = colStr.charAt(0);
 //Logger.log(colLtr+":"+colLtr); Should output something like "P:P"
 var range = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(colLtr+":"+colLtr);
```

I am selecting the first row, creating an array of values, & searching that array fairly simply.  The part I think is clunky is composing a whole column range. In A1 notation, this looks like "A:A".

Maybe I am over-thinking the point that there should be a `lookupCol(String)` function, or even a `getRangeOfCol(Index)` function.

Comment: Your code looks ok, but can you give an example of what output you're expecting. Currently, if your sheet has the text 'Header Label' in column D, it will return a range of D:D in a different sheet.

Comment: This code currently produces the output I want. If "Header Label" is the label for column D, the range produced is indeed D:D, I just thought this current code was a little convoluted and unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
 var comCol = headers[0].indexOf('Header Label');
 var comLtr= String.fromCharCode( 65 + comCol );
 var range = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(comLtr +":"+colLtr);
```

Comment: `String.fromCharCode( 65 + comCol );` will only work for the first 26 columns (A...Z), not for the subsequent ones (AA..ZZ)

Answer (score 0):

To allow for columns AA and beyond, with the assumption the header label is in row 1, I changed the line defining colLtr to:

```
var colLtr = colStr.substr(0, colStr.indexOf('1'));
```